# How do I open and follow a file in Dart (like tail -f)?

Tags: dart, dart-io

Is there an easy way to open a file and continously read from it without the stream getting closed on EOF? Like the Unix command `tail -f`.

Just reading until `EOF` is described in the API docs. But I can't see an obvious/simple way to block or pause the stream for more input.

One solution would be to repeatedly reopen the file and continue reading from the last known length when I detect that the file size has changed.

Answer (score 1):

Somethink like this

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> args ) {
  var file = new File("test.txt");
  print(file.absolute);
  var openFuture = file.open(mode: FileMode.READ);
  openFuture.then((raf) => raf.length().then((len) => raf.setPosition(len)
      .then((raf) => raf.readXxx...
}
```

You can also use `Directory.watch` to get notified about changes and then reopen and read from the last known position.

Answer (score 1):

(even though this questions is a bunch of years old now, I stumbled across the same issue today and couldn't find a viable solution and therefore had to roll my own and wanted to share my findings with future generations of Dart programmers. ;-))

The `dart:io` package in conjunction with a bit of stream and async-await magic should offer everything that is needed to achieve a "*tail -f*"-like functionality:

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:io';

Stream<List<int>> tail(final File file) async* {
  final randomAccess = await file.open(mode: FileMode.read);
  var pos = await randomAccess.position();
  var len = await randomAccess.length();
  // Increase/decrease buffer size as needed.
  var buf = Uint8List(8192);

  Stream<Uint8List> _read() async* {
    while (pos < len) {
      final bytesRead = await randomAccess.readInto(buf);
      pos += bytesRead;

      yield buf.sublist(0, bytesRead);
    }
  }

  // Step 1: read whole file
  yield* _read();

  // Step 2: wait for modify events and read more bytes from file
  await for (final event in file.watch(events: FileSystemEvent.modify)) {
    if ((event as FileSystemModifyEvent).contentChanged) {
      len = await (randomAccess.length());
      yield* _read();
    }
  }
}
```

This function (`tail`) might then be used like that:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  final file = File('/var/log/messages');
  tail(file).transform(utf8.decoder).transform(LineSplitter()).forEach((line) {
    // Do something with the line that has been read, e.g. print it out...
    print(line);
  });
}
```